# Getting Started - No Jobs, No Community Lots, No Rabbit Holes

Tags: the-sims-3

I just downloaded the Sims 3 from Steam (yes, i know I'm late to the party). The first thing I did was get rid of all the crap that comes with a new neighborhood, leaving nothing but empty lots.

The computers and newspapers are not offering me any jobs at all, and there aren't any "rabbit holes" (which I learned about trying to research the problem) that I'm able to plop down into empty lots.

How do I get my Sims employed? What the hell am I missing? The only community lot is a park, and then a bunch of houses I can place into residential lots.

As an example, I learned that you can go to the "Office Building" rabbit hole to get some jobs, but there aren't any. I see no way of designating lots as office buildings, nor placing any of them.

I really have tried to look this up, but I've come up with nothing. I'm prepared to eat humble pie here; I would just like to play the game.

I only have the base, no expansions.

Is it really possible to bulldoze buildings that break the game and then not replace them?

Comment: In Sims 3 the jobs are tied to the lots? In the older ones it didn't matter; I always assumed the Sim was leaving the neighbourhood to work (particularly with jobs like the Army).

Comment: @Jason_c_o Yes, the Sims 3 uses an open world, unlike the previous games. So you actually see your sims get out of the house, take transportation to work and get in the building while they work. If there's no workplace, there's no work.

Answer (score 6):

Well, look at it this way: You're sending your sims out to look for work after bulldozing every local business in the city! Of course they aren't going to be able to find jobs!

In all seriousness, in your effort to start from scratch, it sounds like you deleted the very rabbit holes you're looking for.

Realistically, you have two options to fix this. The first is to simply start over, and be a little less judicious with what lots you bulldoze.

Alternatively, if you create a second Sunset Valley file, you can go into edit neighborhood mode and "Save to Bin" the rabbit hole lots you need. Since the bin exists across neighborhoods, you will then be able to plop down whatever missing rabbit holes you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the missing rabbit holes without having to copy them to the bin from other neighborhoods.  If you go into build mode, there is a button that looks kind of like a small store front.  in there you will find prebuilt rabbithole buildings. You can just place one you want them to work at for now if you want.

If you are really ambitious though, you can download rabbit hole replacement rugs or doors ( http://modthesims.info/d/435107 )  and use them to build your own building. Just make sure you read the placement restrictions, otherwise they won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The sims is not a building game, however building a complete neighborhood by yourself is possible but time consuming.

The question is why you want to start the sims in an empty neighborhood? If you want to import all your own or downloaded buildings you should do that before you start playing your sim/household. If you just want you own sims then you should move all other out of there houses, the problem is you need to cheat or work very hard to put some rich sims in those villa's.

The game is not broken, but what do you expect from the game? You can perfectly play it without any buildings, start a garden for a money tree, train endlessly on a home-trainer and find some vegies for nutrition. I believe some default sims still visit your home like the mailboy and you could chat up with the pizza deliverer to not go mad from loneliness.

But the sims is all about interacting with the environment and AI, so reload the neighborhood or rebuild it to your own liking by making your own buildings or download them.

Comment: Still not sure if you are trolling us though :)

Comment: The Sims is TOTALLY a building game. According to wikipedia (though the citation seems to have soured): "The game was originally designed as an architecture simulation alone, with the Sims there only to evaluate the houses, but during development it was decided that the Sims were more interesting than originally anticipated and their once limited role in the game was developed further."
[Second-to-last paragraph, "Gameplay" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims_(video_game))